# Using request with Gatsby

Tags: node.js, gatsby

I am trying to add the `request` module to fetch some data, but I am having trouble, given, that it somehow relies on the `fs` module
Installing it and requiring it lands me this error: 

`This dependency was not found: fs, tls, net
To install it, you can run: npm install --save fs tls net`

Installing tls and net seems to fix them (as they don't appear after that) but the fs issue remains. I've checked multiple issues about Webpack and request, but modifying my webpack config didn't help much.

How can I get request to work in a Gatsby website?
Thank you and good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request doesn't work on the frontend.

Use https://github.com/axios/axios instead.

Comment: I also came across https://github.com/iriscouch/browser-request which seems like a good fit

Comment: That could work too. Axios does seem like the gold standard these days though for ajax clients.